# How to get selected buttons from form in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

The user needs to select 3 subjects from the list before they can submit. They can select and unselect options. Everything is functioning as supposed to. Except inserting the values of the button into the database after submission. After I select 3 buttons and click submit

I get the errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: selectedButton
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

and it doesn't update `subject1`, `subject2`, `subject3` values for the user on the db.

Form Element

```html
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <label for="subjects">Select your school subjects select 3:</label><br>
    <button type="button" name="selectedButton" class="redirect-button" value="math" onclick="selectButton(this)">Math</button>
    <button type="button" name="selectedButton" class="redirect-button" value="science" onclick="selectButton(this)">Science</button>
    <button type="button" name="selectedButton" class="redirect-button" value="english" onclick="selectButton(this)">English</button>
    <button type="button" name="selectedButton" class="redirect-button" value="history" onclick="selectButton(this)">History</button>
    <button type="button" name="selectedButton" class="redirect-button" value="adv_math" onclick="selectButton(this)">Advanced Math</button>
    <button type="button" name="selectedButton" class="redirect-button" value="calculus" onclick="selectButton(this)">Calculus</button>
    <button type="button" name="selectedButton" class="redirect-button" value="other" onclick="selectButton(this)">Other</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" disabled>Submit</button>
    Selected: <span class="badge badge-light ml-2" id="selectedCount">0</span>/3
</form>
```

PHP

```php
<?php

include 'config.php';
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $selectedButtons = $_POST['selectedButton'];
    $subject1 = $selectedButtons[0];
    $subject2 = $selectedButtons[1];
    $subject3 = $selectedButtons[2];

    // Insert the subjects into the database
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `user_form` SET subject1 = '$subject1', subject2 = '$subject2', subject3='$subject3' WHERE id = '$user_id'") or die('query failed');
}

?>
```

JS

```javascript
let selectedCount = 0;
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
const submitButton = form.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
const selectedCountSpan = document.getElementById("selectedCount");

function selectButton(button) {
  if (button.classList.contains("btn-selected")) {
    // Unselect the button
    button.classList.remove("btn-selected");
    selectedCount--;
  } else if (selectedCount < 3) {
    // Select the button
    button.classList.add("btn-selected");
    selectedCount++;
  }

  // Update the selected count display and enable or disable the submit button
  selectedCountSpan.textContent = selectedCount;
  submitButton.disabled = selectedCount === 0;
}
```

I tried separating the values individually from the array but it seems like the values are all null.

```php
$subject1 = $selectedButtons[0];
$subject2 = $selectedButtons[1];
$subject3 = $selectedButtons[2];
```

Comment: Button values aren't sent to the server (except for the submit button that sends the form). Use checkboxes or radio buttons. Or have the JavaScript fill in a hidden input with button values.